# integral parameterization in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, integral

I want to use integral function which is parameterized. but it gives an error. the upper limit in integral function is a parameter.

my code is here:

```
f1=@(t) (25.46/t)+0.01519
antf1=integral(f1,298.15,t)
```

but, for example, the following code does not give any error:

```
f2=@(t) 25.46*(1.519*t/100)
antf2=integral(f2,298.15,t)
```

thank you all.

**UPDATE 1**

the complete code is here:

```
clc
clear
i=1;
j=1;
a=1.4979e-06;
b=1.9829e-05;
r=0.00008314;
for t=173.15:10:423.15
    tr=t/154.6;
    for p=1:1:100
        pr=p/50.45;
        aa=( 1.4084*(1-(t/154.6)^0.5 ))^2;
        eq=[p -((3*b*p)+(r*t)) -((r*2*t*b)-(aa*a*b)+(3*p*(b^2))) (((b^3)*p)-(aa*a*b)+(r*t*(b^2)))];
        rr=roots(eq);
        rq=rr(1);
        v(i,j)=rq;
        bb=(r*154.6/50.45)*((0.083-(0.422/(tr^1.6)))+(0.022*(0.139-(0.172/(tr^4.2)))));
        zv(i,j)=1+((pr/tr)*(bb*50.45/(r*154.6)));
        %z(i,j)=(v(i,j)*p)/(r*t);
        fun1= @(t) 25.46+(1.519*t/100) ;%-(0.7151*(t^2)/100000)+(1.311*(t^3)/1000000000);
        fun2= @(p) ((p/(t*r))*(r*154.6/50.45)*((0.6752*(154.6^1.6)/(t^0.6))+((0.7224*(154.6^4.2)/(t^3.2)))))-(p*bb/(r*(t^2)));
        infun1=integral(fun1,298.15,t);
        infun2=integral(fun2,1,p);
        h(i,j)= infun1 - (r*(t^2))*infun2;
        f1= @(t) (25.46/t)+0.01519 ;
        f2= @(p) ((1/(t*r))*(r*154.6/50.45)*((0.6752*(154.6^1.6)/(t^0.6))+((0.7224*(154.6^4.2)/(t^3.2)))))-(1*bb/(r*(t^2)));
        f3= @(p) (p*t/(50.45*154.6))*(bb*50.45/(r*154.6));
        anf3=integral(f1,298.15,t);    %%%%%%%%%%% LINE 28 %%%%%%%%%%%
        anf4=integral(f2,1,p);
        anf5=integral(f3,1,p);
        s(i,j)=anf3-(r*log(p/1))+(r*((-1)*t*anf4)-anf5);
        i=i+1;
    end
    i=1;
    j=j+1;
end
v;
%z;
zv;
h;
s;
```

the error message is shown in the following:

```
Error using  / 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in code>@(t)(25.46/t)+0.01519

Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 314)
                fx = FUN(t);

Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 132)
            [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

Error in integralCalc (line 75)
        [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AtoBInvTransform,interval);

Error in integral (line 88)
Q = integralCalc(fun,a,b,opstruct);

Error in code (line 28)
        anf3=integral(f1,298.15,t);
```

Comment: This can not be all the code, because it would error for undefined `t`.

Comment: thank you @AnderBiguri ,
I updated the question. the complete code and the error message get added.

Comment: Use elementwise division: `f1=@(t) (25.46./t)+0.01519`. You may need this in many other places.

Comment: Your problem is that, as stated in the [doc](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html#btbbkta-1-fun), whatever function you pass to `integral` must accept vector arguments. The suggestion by @AnderBiguri should have you meet this requirement if you apply it.